# Use search output string to open a local network file

Tags: php, search, lucidworks

I have been trying for ages with all types of "file, file_get_contents, fopen, opendir and etc" to acomplish what I am triying to do, but just no can do for me, this goes beyong my understanding, sadly. But here I am to learn.

What I want to do? I work with LucidWorks, and I have built an Intranet search that searches the specific path given "C://example/example/..." and does a full text search through all the files. The output of the search on my intranet website is simple:

- Document title
- Body title with highlighted keyowrds
- Path to the file

Now, that not being enough, my lazy fellow Companions would like to be able to click the Document title(which does indeed have a full path to the document behind it, just so you can picture it better "C:/Ex/ex/ex/docs/sap/text.txt(or any other termination)) and open it locally.

Here is the part of the code that I believe to be relevant for what I am trying to acomplish. The "solution" i have built in does not work, but it may give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish here.

```
$searchParams = array(
                'hl' => 'true',
                'hl.fl' => 'body'
            );

            $response = $LWS->search($query, $offset, $limit, $searchParams);

            if ($response->response->numFound > 0) {

                foreach ($response->response->docs as $doc) {
                    ?>

                    <div id="resultbox">
                        <span id="resulttitle"> <?php echo "<a href={$doc->id}'>{$doc->title}</a><br />"; ?> </span> 

                        <?php
                        $content = (("{$doc->id}'>{$doc->title}"));
                        print_r( '<a href= ' . fopen(str_replace('%', ' ', $content), "r+") . '>Open File</a><br />');
                        ?>

                        <SPAN ID="copytext"  >
                            <?php echo substr($content, -100); ?> 
                            <br></SPAN>

                        <div id="sbody">
                            <?php
                            echo "..." . $response->highlighting->{$doc->id}->body[0] . "...<br /><br />";
                        }
                        echo '<br />';
                        return;
                    } else {
                        echo "No results for \"" . $query . "\"";
                        return;
                    }
                    ?>
```

There is a little bit more code above it, but it's irrelevant for the asked question.

So there you go folks, I am hoping for help, and to be able to learn something new :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say that your solution doesn't work? Does it output any errors? Or is the output just different from the expected output?

Comment: I either get an output error, as following : `Warning: fopen(file:/C:/Users/dominikf/Desktop/TestUti/Test 20Sap 20Uti 20Test 20Sap 20Uti 20 20- 20Kopie 20(10).txt'>) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\Intranet_Server\searcher.php on line 55` or the link to the files just redirects me to the files.php(where the content is displayed). The row 55 is the section `print_r( '<a href= ' . fopen(str_replace('%', ' ', $content), "r+") . '>Open File</a><br />');`  of the code! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you're trying to put the contents of the files into the `href` attribute of you anchor/link (`<a>`) tag.

What you need to be doing, instead, is using a url which links to the specified file. This could possibly look like this in your implementation;

```
print_r('<a href="' . $content . '">Open File</a><br />');
```

and the output would look something like;

```
<a href="file:/C:/path/to/your/file.txt">Open File</a><br />
```

Comment: I had been this far aswell, this does indeed show the "Open file" with the right path behind it, still tho, it will not open the directory. I do know the modern browsers block this behaviour, but I would not know how to work around this. :(

Comment: If you type the path directly into the browser url, does it show the file in the browser?

Comment: Yes it does. For first that would be a great solution, a long term solution would be if it opens the file in the corresponding programm. Ie PDF in acrobat, .doc in Microsoft word, etc....

Comment: That's a different problem.. and you'll likely find that it's entirely dependant on how the user has their browser set up I'm afraid, so I don't think you'll be able to force it to open in another application rather than the browser..

Comment: That would be good enough tho, but the problem remains, it does not open in the browser. If I would get it to that point, I could possibly add a texteditor, that would be sufficient for first integration in the system. Any other solutions could be found in the future. But if anyone comes up with a solution to actually open the file localy, that would be great!

Comment: I'm not even sure what the problem is anymore then. The URL that you've got in the variable `$content` - if you paste it into the URL bar, it goes to file, but it's not working when used in the link?

Comment: It seems to be that the shown link is user friendly, meaning: C:/docs/test/test/tes document.txt, while the link output when copying it displays something like this file:///C:/Users/dominikf/Desktop/TestUti/Test%20Sap%20Uti%20Test%20Sap%20Uti%20%20-%20Kopie%20(10).txt%27%3E.